# Tikz matrix with multiple styles not working

Tags: tikz-styles, tikz-matrix

I have a Tikz picture that contains a matrix.
I would like to center the header text and highlight some specific cells.
It is important that it is a matrix and not a tabular.

I have tried the following:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,snakes,automata,backgrounds,petri, fit,positioning,matrix}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{
    state/.style={
           %draw=black,
           nodes={
             %text width=width(":pi2"),
             align=left,
             anchor=west
           },
           inner sep=2pt,
            matrix of nodes,
           },
           row 1/.style = {nodes={anchor=base }}
}
\tikzset{highlight/.style args = {(#1,#2)}{row #1 column #2/.style={fill=red!50,minimum width=1cm}}}

\begin{tikzpicture}[]

 \matrix[state,highlight/.list={(2,4),(3,4),(4,4)}] (IT) 
 {%
    S & P & O & C \\ \hline
    :book & :title & ``Dracula'' & :pi1  \\
    :book & :author & :stoker & :pi1  \\
    :stoker & :name & ``Bram Stoker'' & :pi2  \\
 };

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The first problem is that the headline in the matrix is not centered? The other cells are set to `anchor=west` and the header is `anchor=base`, however, this does not do as expected.

I have found a Tikz guide that showed how to make a Tikz style that receives arguments, but I do not work when combined with my other style. How can I both style my matrix and highlight some cells? 
It is not a bad option to hard code the highlighting because the `state` style is used by other matrixes that have different highlighting.

Cheers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you are missing `nodes` at some places. Other than that, note that the column width is not necessarily the width of the node inside them. You can add `draw` option to see this. Hence I've added 1cm minimum width to have some space within the node for center alignment.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{
    state/.style={
           %draw=black,
           nodes={
             %text width=width(":pi2"),
             align=left,
             anchor=west
           },
           inner sep=2pt,
            matrix of nodes,
           },
           row 1/.style = {nodes={align=center,minimum width=1cm}}
}
\tikzset{highlight/.style args = {(#1,#2)}{row #1 column #2/.style={nodes={fill=red!50,minimum width=1cm}}}}

\begin{tikzpicture}[]

 \matrix[state, highlight/.list={(2,4),(3,4),(4,4)}] (IT) 
 {%
    S & P & O & C \\ \hline
    :book & :title & ``Dracula'' & :pi1  \\
    :book & :author & :stoker & :pi1  \\
    :stoker & :name & ``Bram Stoker'' & :pi2  \\
 };

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I was so close, thank you for pointing out the mistakes. Have a good day